# How to fill a document template in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have to fill a (markdown) document template with the output of different commands. To make it simple suppose you have a template like this (my one is much more complicated):

```
$ cat sample_template.txt
Memory availability:
--------------------
<insert free output here>

Storage availability:
---------------------
<insert df output here>
```

How to insert each command output in the right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`m4`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/m4):

```
$ cat sample_template.txt
Memory availability:
--------------------
INSERT_FREE_OUTPUT_HERE

Storage availability:
---------------------
INSERT_DF_OUTPUT_HERE

$ m4 -DINSERT_FREE_OUTPUT_HERE="$(free)" -DINSERT_DF_OUTPUT_HERE="$(df -h)" < sample_template.txt

Memory availability:
--------------------
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:                  <my memory details get printed here>
-/+ buffers/cache:    <my memory details get printed here>
Swap:                 <my memory details get printed here>

Storage availability:
---------------------
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
<my filesystem details get printed here>
```

Comment: Oh wow, m4! I'm a bit divided here. On one hand, it's a perfect fit for this particular task. On the other hand, it can be really arcane if your task is even a little bit different. I would not recommend a more popular tool like `sed` here, but this answer should perhaps at least note that there are more ways to skin a cat; and/or perhaps this question should be closed as a duplicate of one of the many similar questions.